# Saving unknown number of identical Dropdowns on a Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've followed Steve Sanderson’s "Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style" guide and created an MVC view to edit a list of items. Note i'm using MVC 3 so i'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

The problem i have is one of the fields on my list is a dropdown list. i've managed to get the dropdown populated on each row but its not loading the selected value when the page loads. It is however saving the selected value but every time i edit the page i need to re-set all the dropdowns.

Does anyone know how to set the selected dropdown value for each "row" on the partial view?

My edit view has

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
{
    @Html.Partial("RoleRow-Edit", item)
}
```

My partial view has

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Roles"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TemplateID)
    @Html.DropDownList("PartyRoleID", (SelectList)ViewBag.PartyRoles)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
}
```

On my controller i have

```
ViewBag.PartyRoles = new SelectList(db.PartyRoles.OrderBy(c => c.Role), "Role", "Role");
```

Comment: I have the same problem and can't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround : you should create the SelectList in the partial view, and set its intial value to the bounded value, so partial view will look like this :

```
@{var selectList = new SelectList(db.PartyRoles.OrderBy(c => c.Role), 
                                 "Role", "Role",Model.PartyRoleID);} 
/*pass the db.PartyRoles.OrderBy(c => c.Role) in view bag inside controller,
it's cleaner*/

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Roles"))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TemplateID)
  @Html.DropDownList(model => model.PartyRoleID, selectList)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you would set the `PartyRoleID` value. I would recommend you to use view models and strongly typed views instead of `ViewBag`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PartyRoleID, Model.PartyRoles)
```

Now all you have to do on your controller is to set the value of your view model:

```
var roles = db.PartyRoles.OrderBy(c => c.Role);
var model = new MyViewModel();
// preselect the value of the dropdown
// this value must correspond to one of the values inside the roles collection
model.PartyRoleID = "admin";
model.PartyRoles = new SelectList(roles, "Role", "Role");
return View(model);
```

Also I would recommend you using Editor Templates and replace the following foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
{
    @Html.Partial("RoleRow-Edit", item)
}
```

By the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Roles)
```

Now all that's left is to customize the corresponding [editor template](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/).